# Deconstructing the js formula for this parallax

Tags: javascript, frontend, parallax

I love this JS Parallax technique used in this website
https://www.beamland.com/

Based on scrolling a set div, change in css VH, showing what is under.

I am trying to reproduce something similar, but I am failing to get the formula of calculating the height of the visible screen vs the scroll, vs the whole height of the document.

So I digged under the hood of that website, but I am not understanding what kind of calculation is being done to achieve the effect.

```
BEAM.initParallax = function() {
    function a() {
        var a = q - 1,
            b = a / j,
            c = Math.ceil(b),
            d = 100 - a % j / j * 100 + "vh",
            e = 100 * b + 4e3 / j + "vh";
        r = !1, "Mobile Safari" !== h.browser.name && "Android" !== h.os.name || (e = a + 30 + "px"), c < 1 && (c = 1), a % j === 0 && a > 0 && c++;
        for (var f = 0; f < m.length; f++) f + 1 > c ? m[f].style.height = "100vh" : f - 1 < c && (m[f].style.height = "0vh");
        m[c - 1] && (m[c - 1].style.height = d), o.removeClass("is-active"), $(o[c - 1]).addClass("is-active"), b < s ? (l.removeAttr("style").addClass("stuck"), n.removeClass("faded")) : l[0].hasAttribute("style") || (n.addClass("faded"), l.removeClass("stuck").css("top", e))
    }

    function b() {
        if (s = 3.887, k <= 1024) {
            s = 3.915;
            var a = Math.abs(j - document.getElementsByClassName("Parallax-spacer")[0].style.height);
            $(".Parallax-spacer").css("height", j + "px"), a > 20 && Math.ceil((q - 1) / j) >= 4 && (p < q && (a *= -1), window.scrollTo(0, q - 4 * a))
        }
    }

    function c() {
        return "Android" === h.os.name ? i.outerHeight() : i.innerHeight()
    }

    function d() {
        return "Android" === h.os.name ? i.outerWidth() : i.outerWidth()
    }

    function e() {
        p = q, q = window.scrollY, f()
    }

    function f() {
        r || window.requestAnimationFrame(a), r = !0
    }
    if ($(".Parallax-Hero").length) {
        var g = new UAParser,
            h = g.getResult(),
            i = $(window),
            j = c(h),
            k = d(h),
            l = $("div.Nav-Main"),
            m = $(".Parallax-panel"),
            n = $(".Parallax-wayfinder"),
            o = n.find(".Parallax-pagination--dot"),
            p = 0,
            q = 0,
            r = !1,
            s = 0;
        b(), $(".Parallax-pagination--dot").on("mouseup touchend", function(a) {
            a.preventDefault();
            var b = $(".Parallax-pagination--dot").index(this),
                c = b * j + 1;
            $("html, body").animate({
                scrollTop: c + "px"
            }, 500)
        }), i.on("scroll", function() {
            e()
        }), i.on("resize", function() {
            j = c(h), k = d(h), b(), e()
        }), window.requestAnimationFrame(a)
    }
```

I even looked at various other parallax and code effect on codepen, but I don't find something similar to this effect, to understand the calculation.
Can someone help me to unveil the logic? Thank you

Comment: The confusion probably stems from the fact that this is not a parallax effect. Parallax is when the background moves slower than the foreground to give an effect that the background is further away. In the example you gave this doesn't happen.

Comment: Yeah I know that parallax is not exactly like that. But the guy that did this, was calling the functions "parallax".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a minified code. For development purposes, you better rename the variables so you could read easily.

```
m = $(".Parallax-panel"),
becomes:
parallaxPanel = $(".Parallax-panel"),
then
m.length
is
parallaxPanel.length

q = window.scrollY
becomes
windowScrollY = window.scrollY
then 
a = windowScrollY - 1;

j = c(h),
becomes
windowHeight = c(h),
```

Try this ad see if you could understend better.

Update:

The reason I suggested this naming convention is for you to understand these calculations better.

```
b = a / j;
```

This is not clear, but:

```
b = (windowScrollY - 1) / windowHeight;
```

is more obvious. window.ScrollY is the number of pixels the document is currently scrolled vertically from the origin. window.outerHeight is window's height.

```
c = Math.ceil(b);
```

b is float so now c is an integer.

```
d = 100 - a % j / j * 100 + "vh";
d = 100 - (windowScrollY - 1) % windowHeight / windowHeight * 100 + "vh";
```

This gives percentage scrolled.

I won't be able to decode it all for you. You should have math and programming knowledge to do it.

Comment: Good tip, but how do I substitute more complex calculation like: 'a = q - 1,
            b = a / j,
            c = Math.ceil(b),
            d = 100 - a % j / j * 100 + "vh" ' there is no reference. I guess that is calculating something but I don't understand what is the logic behind this.

Comment: Thx for the updated comment. Now it is much more clear.